# Can't find local disks

Tags: disk

I did a full installation of Ubuntu on my system but I can't seem to find my 900GB HDD that I have on my PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your launcher there is something that looks like a filing cabinet. This is called Nautilus. Click on it and you should be able to explore all your drives and the folders/directories within.

Assuming you installed Ubuntu on your 900 GB HDD you'll be seeing it with Nautilus. If you installed Ubuntu on a different drive, like a 128 GB SSD boot drive, you'll still be able to navigate to the 900 GB HDD and see the files there.

Comment: I only see one drive, but I'm sure I have 2 one a 99GB SSD and a 900GB HDD. Did they somehow merge into one? Is it due to me not partitioning it? I thought I won't need to since I was going for a full install.

Comment: Oh yes I do believe a new drive needs to be partitioned and branded with a file system such as EXT4 or NTFS,  etc. I would avoid btrfs myself.